# How to export .mbtiles file from PostGIS to serve with S3

Tags: postgis, vector-tiles

We store our data in a PostGIS database. The database is updated roughly every week. However we do not want to serve vector tiles directly from our PostGIS but would much rather export a .mbtiles file to S3. The only option we see at the moment is exporting the PostGIS data to GeoJSON and afterwards using tippecanoe to bake the tiles. Is there a direct way to generate an .mbtiles file from a PostGIS database which can then be used by a static tile hosting service like S3?

Comment: Export from POSTGIS directly https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVT.html and use a tool like rclone(rsync) to s3 https://rclone.org/

Comment: GDAL MVT driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html should be able to write directly into .mbtiles  with `-dsco FORMAT=MBTILES`.

Comment: ST_AsMVT gives you a vector tile. It does not give you a .mbtiles file which is actually a sqlite db with all the tiles in it. GDAL does indeed write to mbtiles-